# How to remove an item from auto-mode-alist (Emacs)

Tags: list, emacs

I thought this would be simple when I tried to do it, however I'm stuck.

When I add *octave-mode* to my ~/.emacs thus:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist ("\\.m$" . octave-mode))
```

Opening an Octave file, .m, I instead end up in the OBJC major mode ... this is because auto-mode-alist contains:

```
(\.m\' . objc-mode)
```

which comes first in the A-list.

I've tried:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (delete '( \.m\' . objc-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

and I've even tried:

```
(setq ama '())
(setq objc '(\.m\' . objc-mode))
   (dolist (item auto-mode-alist)
      (if (not (eq (cdr (last objc)) (cdr (last item))))
          (setq ama (list ama item))))
 (setq auto-mode-alist ama)
```

Any suggestions on either removing the objc-mode from the alist or ensuring that octave-mode supercedes it would be great.

Comment: `auto-mode-alist` contains `("\\.m\\'" . objc-mode)` by default. Where are you seeing `(\.m\' . objc-mode)` with not-double-quoted string syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are essentially two questions here. One is how to remove the element from the list. The other is how to automatically open `*.m` files in octave-mode. You shouldn't need to remove the element to override it. The provided form

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist ("\\.m$" . octave-mode))
```

causes an error. Instead you should use

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.m$" . octave-mode))
```

or better yet:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.m\\'" . octave-mode))
```

These two forms will add the element to the beginning of the association list, meaning filenames will be checked against it first, never making it to the objc-mode element lower down the list.

If you really want to remove the element from the list, here are a couple of ways.

One way that only deletes the exact cons cell `'("\\.m\\'" . objc-mode)`:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (delete '("\\.m\\'" . objc-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

Another way that will delete anything in the association list associated with `"\\.m\\'"`:

```
(require 'cl-lib)
(cl-remove "\\.m\\'" auto-mode-alist :test 'equal :key 'car)
```

Comment: Apparently `delete` already delete the item from the original list, you may want to use `remove` in its place, or just the internal command `(delete '("\\.m\\'" . objc-mode) auto-mode-alist)`

Answer (score 1):

There's three obstacles here:

1. Quoting and regexp syntax at the same time
2. `assq-delete-all` (the obvious choice) uses `eq` to compare the keys, which only succeeds (and thus deletes) it finds *the same object* - it won't succeed if it sees only *an identical string*
3. `assq-delete-all` does not guarantee to modify the list, so another *setq* is necessary

The solution is clear: find the *car* object in the alist. Like:

> (setq auto-mode-alist (assq-delete-all (car (rassoc 'objc-mode auto-mode-alist)) auto-mode-alist))

After that, You can

> (setq auto-mode-alist (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\.m\'" . octave-mode)))

Answer (score 0):

To add to what was already said, for completion.

For some modes, the `auto-mode-alist` contains several different entries associating different file extensions to a mode.  For example, the racket-mode uses 3 entries:

```lisp
...
 ("\\.rktl\\'" . racket-mode)
 ("\\.rktd\\'" . racket-mode)
 ("\\.rkt\\'" . racket-mode)
...
```

If you want to remove those, the single `assq-delete-all` on the mode symbol is not sufficient, you must loop with something like this:

```lisp
  (while (rassoc 'racket-mode auto-mode-alist)
    (setq auto-mode-alist
          (assq-delete-all (car (rassoc 'racket-mode auto-mode-alist))
                           auto-mode-alist))))
```

I ran on this issue with racket-mode because the built-in scheme-mode associate the `.rtk` files with `scheme-mode` and this association was closer to the head of the `auto-mode-alist` than the ones to racket-mode.  Trying to add a new one failed because it was already present.  To be able to have racket-mode used with .rkt files while scheme-mode still available for other scheme files, I had to remove the racket-mode entries first and them add them back, placing them in front of the association with the scheme-mode.